# cast to generic type at runtime

Tags: vb.net, generics, reflection

Ok, i don't think this is possible so I thought I would ask to make sure. I'm in the process of creating a function which reflects over the properties in a class and adds them to this data structure I have. Some of the properties are generic types.

So say we have `DataType(Of T)` that has a `.Value` property of type `T`:

```
Dim properties = GetType(MyType).GetFields(Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or _
                                           Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
For Each prop As fieldinfo In properties
   Collection.Add(prop.Name,prop.GetValue(poco))
Next
```

In the `collection.Add` for primitive types (`Integer`, `String`, etc.…) I just want to add the type... but in the case of generic I want to add the `DataType(Of T).Value`. I hope there is some work-around but I don't think there is a way because the type of `T` can not be determined at compile time right? Ideally `DirectCast(prop.getvalue(poco), DataType(Of T)).Value` would be possible. This is when you hoped even more dynamics appear than whats in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891797/typecasting-generic-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just occurred to me that I may have mis-read your question. Therefore another answer from me.

You can avoid the need to cast to a generic type (where you don't know the type parameter) at runtime by introducing a new interface that allows access to some `Value` property:

```
Public Interface IHasValue
    Public ReadOnly Property Value As Object
End Interface
```

Next, make sure your `DataType(Of T)` class implements this interface. This means that each `DataType(Of T)` object (no matter what concrete type `T` is) is also an `IHasValue`, and you will be able to check this with `TypeOf(…) Is IHasValue`:

```
Public Class DataType(Of T) : Implements IHasValue

    Public Value As T

    Public ReadOnly Property UntypedValue As Object Implements IHasValue.Value
        Get
            Return Me.Value
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

(This duplication of `Value` is necessary for two reasons: First it is necessary when `DataType(Of T).Value` is a field instead of a property, and second because they do not have the same type.)

Then, where you fill your collection with fields, you can check whether a particular field is an `DataType(Of T)` (and if so, unwrap the `Value` from it) by doing the following:

```
Dim value As Object = prop.GetValue(poco)

If TypeOf(value) Is IHasValue Then         ' <- is value a DataType(Of T) ?    '
    value = CType(value, IHasValue).Value  ' <- if so, unwrap the value        '
End If

Collection.Add(prop.Name, value)
```

---

This is probably more what you're after than my other answer, but let me emphasise this:

> ***`If TypeOf(…) Is … Then …` is a code smell**. Perhaps you should re-think your code and investigate solutions involving polymorphism.*

Comment: thanks a lot stakx for the help. Excellent solution. Ya the better solution would be to return a Basic Type call it just BasicType and return that rather than type T. BasicType would just hold type T but you wouldn't have to worry about casting in that case. Unfortunately that would require way to much code revisit because this thing is used all over and very few people used the interface. Anyways thanks so much for the help