# Generic Casting doesn't work with overloaded Assignment Operator

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, operator-overloading

#### Setup

I have a class with an [overloaded assignment operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf7b9sy7.aspx)

```vb
Public Class Timestamp

    ReadOnly _value As String

    Public Sub New(value As String)
        Me._value = value
    End Sub

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal input As String) As Timestamp
        Return New Timestamp(input)
    End Operator

End Class
```

This allows both of the following widening conversions to occur:

```vb
Dim t1 As Timestamp = "1314"
Dim t2 As Timestamp = CType("1314", Timestamp)
```

So it will happily change from type `String` into type `Timestamp`.

#### Problem

However, if I have a method that takes Timestamp as a generic, the conversion no longer works.
For example, for the following method:

```vb
Private Function GenericCast(Of T)(input As Object, output As T) As T
    Return CType(input, T)
End Function
```

If I call it like this:

```vb
Dim t3 as Timestamp
t3 = GenericCast("1314", t3)
```

I'll get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Timestamp'.
>   [image: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Timestamp'.]

But we already know that I definitely can convert between those types.
Why does it it not work with Generics at runtime?

Comment: That is odd because  I have a generic collection class that does almost exactly the same thing (CType a boxed value back to the desired type).   Trying to tease out the difference.  This might be a [solution (long way around):](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2891797/1070452).

Comment: That is not possible, it's only for ***interfaces***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential solution is to use `CTypeDynamic` instead of `CType`.

```
Private Function GenericCastV2(Of T)(input As Object, output As T) As T
    output = CTypeDynamic(Of T)(input)
    Return output
End Function
```

I know this does not answer your "why" question, but it would just be supposition on my part.  My gut answer is that it has to do with the decisions that the VB compiler makes in deciding which helper method to call to complete conversion.  As a potential clue to the problem, following concept function will not event compile as valid conversion from String for all types would be required.

```
Private Function GenericCastConcept(Of T)(input As Object, output As T) As T
    output = CType(input.ToString, T)
    Return output
End Function
```

Comment: Very cool indeed. `CTypeDynamic` does the trick and is probably more applicable to casts to a generic type anyway.